# model association with a scope for trashable module

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a trashable concern that allows a user to trash ("delete") certain things.

The issue is that even though that item can be trashed, it still has to be referenced if you view something older. If you do that now it won't find that object as I've changed the `default_scope` to only show where trashed is false.

Here's my trashable module:

```
module Trashable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    default_scope   { where(trashed: false) }
    scope :trashed, -> { unscoped.where(trashed: true) }
    validates :trashed, inclusion: { in: [true, false] }
  end

  def trash
    update_attribute :trashed, true
  end
end
```

now I have an `Order` model, where you can view an order. If we for example trash a product, I still want the user to be able to look at their order and see the product.

Now I'm not able to access that with a model association such as:

`has_many :products` and make it so that it includes both where trashed is false and true.

Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Comment: I think you can go with this [gem](https://github.com/ActsAsParanoid/acts_as_paranoid)

Comment: but can you specify that explicitly: `has_many :products, { unscope(:where).where trashed: [true, false] }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by several ways, here is what I know

**Solution 1** Define `with_trashed` like this:

```
module Trashable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    default_scope   { where(trashed: false) }
    scope :trashed, -> { unscoped.where(trashed: true) }

    # Define a new scope here
    scope :with_trashed, -> { unscope(where: :trashed) }
    validates :trashed, inclusion: { in: [true, false] }
  end

  def trash
    update_attribute :trashed, true
  end
end
```

Then you can use it like:

```
order.products.with_trashed
```

**Solution 2** Define unscoped class

```
class UnscopedProduct < Product
  self.default_scopes = []
  belongs_to :order
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
  has_many :unscoped_products, foreign_key: :order_id, class_name: "UnscopedProduct"
end
```

Then you can use it like:

```
order.unscope_products
```

As my experience, I would use Solution 1, but there are some weird cases, this doesn't work anymore, for example, in a complex query, so remember solution 2, it will save a lot of time!

Using `Default scope` will lead to so many problems for later complex queries. That depends on you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do a couple of things:

1. As someone mentioned in the comment, you should use [Acts as Paranoid](https://github.com/ActsAsParanoid/acts_as_paranoid) Gem that is exactly meant for this purpose. Using that, you can use methods `with_deleted` or `only_deleted` that will return you relevant deleted objects as well.
2. You cannot simply use `unscoped` as you are doing above. Unscoped will remove all the conditions and not only `trashed: false`. You can also try to create another scope which returns you deleted objects and merge the objects found in the second scope with the first one.

`scope_1_results + scope_2_results`

If you are on Rails 5, you can also `OR` the scopes which is not possible in Rails 4.x or less.